How to track the loading status when fetching data in recoil js for state management in react
I'm learning how to use recoil, I'm stuck to figure out a way to update the atom responsible to track the data fetching status like : idle, loading, succeeded, failed. I've worked with redux and zustand. I was trying to figure out if there's any way we can implement the loading status functionality while the API is being called.
// Atom to hold the userId
export const userIdState = atom<number>({
  key: 'userIdState',
  default: 1, // Starting with user 1
});

// Atom to hold the user fetching status
export const userStatusState = atom<'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'>({
  key: 'userStatusState',
  default: 'idle',
});

// Atom to hold error messages (if any)
export const userErrorState = atom<string | null>({
  key: 'userErrorState',
  default: null,
});


export const userSelector = selector({
  key: 'userSelector',
  get: async ({ get }) => {
    const userId = get(userIdState); // Get the current userId
    // set the status to loading
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch user');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      // set the status to succeeded
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      // set the status to failed
      throw error;
    }
  },
});

